# Return Grid to original Column & Row location

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a main grid (10 columns/ 10 rows) with a few "sub-grids". The column/row locations of these "sub-grids" are set using bindings and change from record to record. Example: subGrid_1 is positioned in the main grid's column 5/row 5. Using a MouseEnter event, subGrid_1 is moved to the main grid's column 1/row 1 with the following code:

```
Grid.SetColumn(subGrid_1,1);
Grid.SetRow(subGrid_1,1);
```

The problem I'm having is finding a way to get subGrid_1 to go back to the original column 5/row 5 location during the MouseLeave event.

Additional Info: There is a "control" grid dedicated to capturing the the MouseEnter\Leave events. This grid is seperate and not affected by the mouse events. When the MouseEnter fires, it correctly moves the subgrid to col 1\row 1, other code hides the remaining subgrids. When the MouseLeave fires, everything returns to normal (visiblilty), except the subgrid stays in col 1\row 1 instead of return to it's original position. The original subgrid positions are kept in a xml doc and change record to record. One thing I noticed - once a subgrid is moved its permanent even if the record changes.

Comment: Which grid are you listening for mouse events on, the grid or the subgrid? If you have it on your subgrid, then you probably won't trigger the event if your code is moving the subgrid out from under your mouse. If you have it on the main grid, please post your code and show us what you're trying.

Comment: What happens when mouse leaves the target area? does it fire the proper event handler?